# Laravel sessions don't remain between requests

Tags: php, laravel

I have two methods, setSession and chkSession.

```
public function setSession()
{
    Session::put('one', $person['id']);
    Session::put('two', $person['firstName']);
    Session::put('three', $person['lastName']);

    return dd(Session::all());      
}

public function chkSession()
{
    dd(Session::all());
}
```

When I execute setSession at `/people/setsession`, I see my session variables intact, when I load the next method, chkSession at `/people/chksession`, I only see the token string and empty flash array.

Why aren't these variables retaining between requests?

Comment: Have you configured your session in `app/config/session.php` as stated here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session ? Is your `app/storage/sessions` writable?

Comment: Yes, I ensured that app/storage/sessions has 777 permissions and I have configured session.php.  I'm using the cookie driver. 'domain' is set to null at the moment. Should I set this to my local.dev:8000 url for my dev server?

Comment: Have you tried another driver? Like a `file` driver?

Comment: Yes, file was set by default. It had the same results

Comment: Do you have `laravel_session` cookie in your browser? Have you tried to run laravel with `'debug' => true` in `app/config/app.php`

Comment: I do see laravel_session in my browser at both people/setsession and /people/chksession, but I don't see my session variables at chksession

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62986/discussion-between-kinsdotnet-and-baldrs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Try using the 'file' driver instead of the 'cookie' driver. Something between your PHP configuration and your browser (cookie blockers, etc) might be messing up the session.</strike>

I think I might know why, I had a similar problem some time ago: you're calling dd(), which calls die(), and at that point Laravel hasn't written the session data to storage yet. What it does is store the session data temporarily in memory and only after everything has been executed, will it dump the session data into storage (file, cookie, redis, whatever).

This means that when you're printing out the session contents in setSession(), Laravel is printing out the correct values because it still has them in memory, even though they haven't yet been written to storage. In chkSession(), though, memory has been wiped and thus Laravel no longer has the data in memory.

Try getting rid of dd() and see if it works.

Comment: I'll try it again now, but it was initially set to file and the result was the same.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I just read that in one of your previous comments, sorry. Have you tried another browser, or maybe an anonymous session in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: No such luck. File had the same result. Trying other browsers now.

Comment: Same thing is happening in Firefox, chrome and Chrome incognito mode.

Comment: It is better sometimes to use brand old `var_dump` with `xdebug` extension, which makes it readable.